# "Connect With twitter" for mobile websites

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I am using @Anywhere code to implement the twitter signup functionality for my website

```
twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
            document.getElementById("signin-btn").onclick = function () {
                T.signIn()
            };
        });
```

Above written is my code to put "Connect with twitter" button on my website.
It redirects me to http://oath.twitter.com/................
and open a regular web page of twitter login for desktop browsers.

instead of the desktop size login page I want to open the mobile version of login page, as my website users will be the mobile users.
So they open my page in mobile, so i want twitters mobile version page to be opened
How can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

It should redirect mobile users to a mobile page automatically. Have you tried testing it on a mobile? Or try setting your browser's User Agent to that of a phone.